# How to detect if the cell being edited belongs to the last row of a defined name range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a defined name call "Input_Range". If a last empty row of the input range is being edited (add value to an empty row), then insert an empty row, automatically.

I have been working on this problem for a few days but no solution.  I can only do:
Worksheet_change event to detect if there data within the defined name range is edited or selected, then insert a row. Even if I edit non-empty row (like the first row of the range), it still adds another row.

Please help!

=========================

I just think about the problem and probably I can do: if there is no empty row in range("Input_range"), then insert an empty row. I have not though about this. Well, still need to learn how to detect if a row of a range is empty but it is better.  I will work on this and if I have problem I please help me.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is from the description. Can you post the code that is giving you trouble?

Comment: As a thought, especially if you are using XL 2007 or 2010, you might consider using a Table ("List" in XL 2003) instead.  they have the functionality of adding a new row with formulas when you fill in the last row, and also have automatic totals, headers and filtering.  http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007Tables.asp

Comment: Thank you. Here is the code http://i49.tinypic.com/2zqc775.jpg  I know it is incomplete as I cannot figure out which is the syntax to detect a cell has been edited in in the last row. In other word if there is an no empty row in range "input" then insert an extra empty row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MRange As Range, rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set MRange = Range("InputRange")

    '~~> Get the last Row of the range
    Set rng = MRange.Range(MRange.Cells(MRange.Rows.Count, 1), _
    MRange.Cells(MRange.Rows.Count, MRange.Columns.Count))

    '~~> Trap changes in the last row of the range
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        'If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            'Application.EnableEvents = False

            'rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        'End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much yes that is what I am looking for.  Something like gridview