# Why won't code in the Worksheet_Change() event run?

Tags: excel, vba

Update: 
If I defined range as input_range from A2:P29. Then If Enter in row 30, then it works.  However, the Input_range is not automatically extended and I would like to shift the whole row down not only last row in the range. How could I achieve these two things?

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593346/how-to-detect-if-the-cell-being-edited-belongs-to-the-last-row-of-a-defined-name)

Starting with the help of Siddharth Rout, I am able to make this work on new Excel file. However, no matter what I tried on this file

[Sample Excel File](https://www.yousendit.com/dl?phi_action=app/orchestrateDownload&rurl=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.yousendit.com%252Ftransfer.php%253Faction%253Dbatch_download%2526send_id%253D1516438217%2526email%253D2abfadb5544bf569a8ad6c428594527b&s=19104&cid=tx-02002207350200000000) - it just does not work. I guess there is some kind of structure to prevent from automating adding row. If so, how can I am able to make the code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're detecting the Worksheet_Change() event, you need to have your code in the worksheet object, not in a module.

Here's how to do it:

1. Alt-F11 to open the VBA editor
2. Copy the Worksheet_Change() sub from Module1
3. Double-click on Sheet6(itemmaster)
4. Paste the code in there

Make sure you see Worksheet and Change in the two drop-downs at the top of the editor.

Note: you should always have Option Explicit turned on to require variable declaration. Read this answer to see how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10653204/138938

[image: Screen-shot of code in worksheet instead of module]

Comment: I did copy the code to Sheet6(itemmaster) but it did not work.

Comment: Can you upload the new file? I'll let you know what went wrong.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in my answer? Because the file you posted had the code in module1, not in the code behind for sheet 6.

Comment: Can you post the new file? I'm sure I can fix it in just a few minutes.

Comment: Okay - If I defined range as input_range from A2:P29. Then If Enter in row 30, then it works.  However, the Input_range is not automatically extended and I would like to shift the whole row down not only last row in the range. How could I achieve these two things?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still not as I expected but I am trying to improve it.

Comment: You might want to post another question as we are solving a new problem. I can show you how to redefine the input_range every time you add a row.